# React - Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am new to react and I am having a problem with router. I already tried several solutions and nothing went right. I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong with my file router or webpack-config, if anyone can help me I would be very thankful.

Error:

[error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3K6h.png)

I believe that if I solve the first error, the rest will correct itself. Since I am new to react, I can't be sure of that. Here is my code.

routes.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

import LoginApp from './loginApp';
import RegisterApp from './registerApp';
import HomeApp from './homeApp';
import error from '../components/error';

const history = createHistory();

const Routes = () => (    
    <Router history={history}>        
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={LoginApp} exact />    
            <Route path='/register' component={RegisterApp} />
            <Route path='/home' component={HomeApp} />  
            <Route component={error} />                                              
        </Switch>                               
    </Router>        
)         

export default Routes;
```

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

import Routes from './main/routes';

const App = (Routes) => {
    render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Routes />
        </AppContainer>,
        document.querySelector('[data-js="app"]')
    )
}

App(Routes)

if(module.hot){
    module.hot.accept('./main/routes', () => {
        const NextApp = require('./main/routes').default

        App(NextApp)
    })
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'js', 'index')        
    ],    
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            modules: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),        
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    module: {        
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: /src/,
                use:{
                    loader: 'standard-loader'
                } 
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },            
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: /src/,
                use:{
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
            } 
        }]
    }
}
```

server.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
const config = require('./webpack.config')

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    stats: { colors: true}
}).listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log("Listening on port 3000...")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your problem isn’t (at first glance) anything to do with the server or webpack. The error is coming from react, from one of your components (read the error).

The error is saying the history property is required but your giving it something undefined, so, your `createHistory()` function is a good culprit.

The react [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) actually say to use `createBrowserHistory()`, and then **only with the Router componepent**, which, to be clear, ***you’re not using***. For some ungodly reason you’ve imported BrowserRouter as Router, but BrowserRouter doesn’t require a history. Manually setting a history with the low level Router is recommend only to sync up histories with state managers, which I can’t see you are doing. In my projects I’ve always used a `<BrowserRouter>` component which takes care of the history.

Something is also wrong with a location prop, but first get your main router working, and I suspect that’ll go away.

Comment: Thanks for your response `<BrowserRouter>` on my first try and it did not work, this code was my last try before giving up and asking here. The problem was not exactly the route, it was the `bundle.js` that was not updating, so it does not matter how many changes I make, it would not work. So my solution was reconfig the webpack and switch back to `<BrowserRouter>`, now everything is working correctly. Thank you Oliver, you've helped me figure out the real problem :)

Comment: I'm glad, and it sounds like you'll be ok. I would recommend trying to post much more concise and focused questions, you should never need to post a whole app! I'd also say, React and Webpack and all that *should* work easily, if you find yourself in knots (like the setup you described just now), chances are there's a more 'reacty' way to do it, which you found!